# Why there is no method for sync folder to s3?

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk

I wonder why there is no methods in javascript aws-sdk to sync local directory , which is present in all other language sdks.

is there is any specific reason for that.

Any idea ??.

Comment: Because it hasn't been put in?

Comment: @Deckerz then what's the way to sync directory to s3

Comment: Do it yourself? There is https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar which can watch folders for files. So you do the initial upload and then watch the folder.

Comment: @Deckerz , sorry i can't understand , can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I think you can use aws-cli, to upload your changes to s3.
Also you can write bash script which will watch for file and re-upload it after changes. 
`aws s3 cp 'your folder name' 's3 bucket name' --recursive`

Comment: @Deckerz , what you meant by initial upload and then watch the folder. please add some example or psedocode

Comment: So you upload everything in the folder, then you watch the folder for changes and either edit old files or upload new. Im not writing basic code for you. You should be able to figure it out.

Comment: There's a 3rd party library, **s3** that has sync directory functionality: https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

Comment: @Deckerz AWS API directory sync is not about watching for changes. It is for uploading an entire directory instead of single files (yes it may be misnamed but it is sort of inspired by `rsync`)

Comment: @slebetman i was talking about implementing it manually as the official api doesn't contain it.

Comment: @slebetman yes you are correct , i used the word 'sync' just for legacy. original operation is to upload entire files inside the directory to s3

Comment: @Deckerz Yes, but you don't use `chokidar` or `fs.watch()` for that. You use something like `find` or `fs.readdir()` or `dirscan`

Comment: @slebetman he said Sync do i thought he mean continuous sync of a directory, not a one time upload

Comment: @Deckerz yes, I was trying to correct your misunderstanding. I was not criticizing you

Comment: @slebetman i tried that npm package already, it not working properly. it hangs in progress. i seen the similar issue reported already in their repository issue page

Comment: @Ram I'm using exactly that package in production for a customer. Maybe it's an OS/platform/filesystem issue?

Comment: @slebetman i am using this package in electron -- 3.0.16 , it's not working

Comment: @slebetman in which platform you are using this package??

Comment: Node.js on Linux. Electron is a bit weird because it is not node.js and also not exactly Chrome

Comment: @slebetman , if the upload got cancelled means , how you handled this situation . next time upload from beginning or where it stopped.

Comment: @McAwesome can able to run this bash script aws s3 cp 'your folder name' 's3 bucket name' --recursive inside my electron app , if that possible can i able to listen events like progress , complete etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194739/discussion-between-ram-and-slebetman).